# FTP 425 Can't open data connection behind IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, ftp

I need to write an application which connects to a FTP server. This FTP server does not allows passive mode connections. I can connect to the FTP server using Filezilla.

I have developed a C# WCF service which connects to this FTP server, using FTPWebRequest class.
    Here are the basic settings of the FTPWebRequest object:

```
ftpreq.Proxy = null;
ftpreq.KeepAlive = true;
ftpreq.UsePassive = false;
```

When I run the WCF service from Visual Studio(Ctrl+F5) it connects to the FTP server and downloads required files without any issues

But when I host the service in my local IIS 7.5, it fails to connect to the FTP server with following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (425) Can't open data connection.

After some googling on this problem, I tried playing around the firewall settings, but it was of no use. Not sure if it is related to some IIS security issue or something else.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is my way:

Start\ Control Panel\ Windows Firewall\ Allowed Programs.

Here! Tick check box at your application to allow it through Windows FireWall. 
Remember! Tick checkbox "Home/Work (private)" as well as checkbox "Public".

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

here is complex solution

step 1
single ftp (non ftps) using two network channels (port and port ranges).
One (tcp:21) for auth, and second, used as data-channel for data.

When configuring ftp on iis, open 21 port for auth and control channel, then in iis control-panel on "FTP Firewall support" specify port range for data (5000-6000) and external ip of network interface married with ftp-server.

step 2
Finally, open tcp:21 in windows firewall and create custon rule, allowing connection on tcp:5000-6000. Restart system (or just restart services).

thats all.

ps. just remember, that ftp on iis using tcp:21 for control/auth and tcp:5000-6000 for data. tcp:5000-6000 may be changes in iis manager 1st, and opened in windows firewall second.

Answer (score 0):

I commented this settings:

> UseBinary, Proxy, KeepAlive, UsePassive

and now works good:

```
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpLocation + remoteDir));
            //reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            //reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            //reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
            //reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
```

This code is from microsoft forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/079fb811-3c55-4959-85c4-677e4b20bea3/downloading-all-files-in-directory-ftp-and-c?forum=ncl

Comment: Of course that setting `UsePassive` to true (or keeping the default true value) helps. But the OP was specifically saying *This FTP server does not allows passive mode connections.*

Comment: Thanks for minus but so works without error code 425.

Comment: But it does not answer this question!

Comment: Although it does not answer THIS question, from google searching my own problem, this question was first on the list AND wertyk's answer solved MY problem. That should be worth something, right?

Answer (score -1):

Same issue happened to me. So I did the following and it fixed it:

- I rebooted the whole FTP server
- After reboot, I launched Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager. The Default FTP Site was stopped. I started it. And that fixed it!